# Adjust jQuery mouseover Sensitivity

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseover, delay

Is there any way to make it so if a user hovers on a link for 2 seconds, then the jQuery is executed?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var t;
$("#foo").hover(
    function() {
        t = setTimeout(function() {
            alert("hover");
        }, 2000);
    },
    function() {
        clearTimeout(t);
    }
);
```

Comment: So, when #foo is hovered over an alert happens?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you use a more recent version of jquery you could simple use the [delay function](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)